# Invalid Control loop error with array

Tags: vbscript

I have a fairly complex look of code where I am looking through multiple control variables.

I am getting an error 'Invalid 'for' loop control variable

the line in questions is

```
  for w(1) = 32 to 127
```

I am more familiar with VBA where I would have zero problem with this statement.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that i will be looping through w(1),w(2),w(3) etc. in the same tree. I initialize the variable as dim x(10) but have also tried dim w() , dim w() redim w(10)

Any thoughts? its a fairly critical aspect of the script; as such I am unwilling to swap out all my w 1,2... for individual variables

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

As per comments I should clarify a Few things:

Essentially there is a alpha numeric association with an ID in a system that I am working with which I was not handed down the key too. So I have a multi-dimensional array of rates that are used for multiplying out costs.

What I am doing is working backwards through invoices and matching a material with very subtle differences that have different pricings. 
For simplicity sake, say theres a 2 dimensional material where AA, AB, ... A9 are all priced through several multiplication factors in what would just be a 2x2 grid. So maintaining a pivot point based on the position in string is very important. For this code you could take tier to mean how many characters in the string (aka how complex the composition of the material):

```
dim x(), w()




for tier = 1 to 2

for w(1) = 32 to 127

x(1)= chr(w(1))



        If tier = 2 then
        for w(2)= 32 to 127
        X(2)=chr(w(2))


        next 
        end if

str = ""

for y = 1 to (tier)

str = trim(str & x(y))

next 

'''msgbox str 'debug



    next 
    end if

str = ""

for y = 1 to (tier)

str = trim(str & x(y))

 next 

 '' msgbox str ' debug

next 'tier
```

This is just an excerpt i pulled to get a basic idea of the structure w/o any calculations. this is in essence what is not working

Comment: As far as I know that's invalid syntax. It needs to be a scalar variable (i.e. an integer), not an array. i.e. `for z = 32 to 127`. Can you clarify what language this is - VBScript or VBA? Also please create minimal code required to reproduce

Comment: In the end... what are you trying to do? Why do you need to use an array to hold your loop variable?

Comment: see edits. it is VBS, I only made reference that i am used to VBA

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Why can i not use a member of an array in a loop? is there no better answer than 'its vbs syntax'? Which i guess i can unwillingly live with and take a different but less efficient approach

Comment: TBH I'm just guessing. It just doesn't look right and the error indicates you can't. Maybe there's a better pattern or library you could use but I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: You can't use an Array it has to be a scalar variable as @Nick.McDermaid has already pointed out. `for w(2)= 32` is invalid syntax. The control variable is just a counter to loop through the Array, you can't make an Array a control variable, needs to be an Integer.

Comment: @Lankymart Okay, I guess I'm against a wall here. If you type that out as an answer ill accept is since i searched and could not find any documentation telling me i couldn't do this; especially strange considering how common i practice this method in VBA. Thanks guys

Comment: @scott here is some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3hh43e(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear, you cannot use an `Array` as the control variable. The definition in [For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3hh43e(v=vs.84).aspx) is even clearer;

> *Numeric variable used as a loop counter. The variable cannot be an array element or an element of a user-defined type.*

This is one of the key differences between VBA and VBScript.

Answer (score -1):

You won't loop through x(1),x(2)...on what you write it's going like this 32(1),33(1)....what type it's your w(1) and how you define him?

Comment: perhaps i was not clear: what i am looking for is to loop

x(1) = 32, x(1)=33 .. (x1)=127

But within that loop, i need x(2) to loop x(2)= 1, x(2) = 2 ...

EDIT: i see what you mean,  I will edit my post so that the variables line up

Comment: I still need to know how you defined x(1)......(dim x(1) as long or what ?)....if you decalre him like this it should work 
dim x(1) as variant

Comment: in vbs variables are not defines as types as to my knowledge. in VBA which i am used to, they are

Comment: VBScript is typeless but it still implicitly casts subtypes of `Variant`. If you declare a variable `Dim w(...)` you are declaring an Array, you can't then go on to use that as a control variable in a `For` loop.